# Why are divs and spans null values when I try to adjust them programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm used to styling logic with Ruby and Java, but I'm new to front end and Javascript. And I'm having an issue with divs and spans either being undefined or null when I try to `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`. I've had to jerry-rig solutions when I shouldn't have to just to adjust a background or add divs.

Latest issue below:

```js
var stars = document.getElementById("starContainer");

function starz() {
  for ( let i = 1; i <= 60; i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    newDiv.className = "star";
    newDiv.style.height = "15px";
    newDiv.style.width = "15px";
    newDiv.style.color = "white";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "star";
    newDiv.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    newDiv.style.background = "radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,1.0) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.0))";
    newDiv.style.left = setLeftPosition();
    newDiv.style.top = setTopPosition();
    
      stars.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

function setLeftPosition(){
  let min = Math.ceil(0);
  let max = Math.floor(1400);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  
  return rand + "px";
}

function setTopPosition(){
  let min = Math.ceil(0);
  let max = Math.floor(490);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  
  return rand + "px";
}
```

```css
#scene {
 position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(0, 24, 63);
  background: linear-gradient(35deg,rgb(0, 24, 63) 10%, rgb(17, 0, 14));
}


#starContainer {
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

  #ground { 
   position: absolute;
  height: 245px;
  width: 650px;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
   margin-top: 800px;
 margin-left: 68%; 
  background-color: rgb(2, 2, 2);
  border-radius: 50px;
} 

#middle-ground {
  z-index: 2;
  position:absolute;
  border-bottom: 175px solid rgb(2, 2, 2);
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  margin-top:792px;
  margin-left: 845px;
}


#slanted-border {
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 115px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  margin-top:845px;
  margin-left: 730px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<!-- title & links to scripts & css---> 
 

<div id="scene" onload="starz()">
  <span id="starContainer">
    <!-- <p> I AM JESUS I AM JESUS</p> -->
  </span>
  <div id="slanted-border"></div>
  <div id="middle-ground"></div>
  <div id="lower-ground"></div>
  <div id="ground"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

So this doesn't work. Logging "stars" (the variable containing starContainer) returns null. And I don't understand what's wrong. Other times I've had fully styled divs that I've had to grab one by one by class name and looping through them resulted in `undefined` and the styled objects having no values.

However, sometimes it works! In that later issue, I brute forced it and grabbed each of those divs by ID, and the code worked. On this one, it works on codepen (if I set it as an onclick, not an onload) and works in the provided fiddle that I used to upload that code snippit, but it doesn't work as an onload, onfocus, or onclick in the actual browser.

Please advise

Comment: Is your JS in the `<head>` or in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page? It could be that the DOM element hasn't been created by the time the JS attempts to reference it.

Comment: The script is linked in the head. That's a good point. But I have a very similar function that places divs in the <header> and that works just fine

Comment: ...I had to move the script into the body. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try moving `var stars = document.getElementById("starContainer");` inside starz function, so it initialized on document load:

```js
function starz() {
  var stars = document.getElementById("starContainer");
  for ( let i = 1; i <= 60; i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    newDiv.className = "star";
    newDiv.style.height = "15px";
    newDiv.style.width = "15px";
    newDiv.style.color = "white";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "star";
    newDiv.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    newDiv.style.background = "radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,1.0) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.0))";
    newDiv.style.left = setLeftPosition();
    newDiv.style.top = setTopPosition();
    
      stars.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

function setLeftPosition(){
  let min = Math.ceil(0);
  let max = Math.floor(1400);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  
  return rand + "px";
}

function setTopPosition(){
  let min = Math.ceil(0);
  let max = Math.floor(490);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  
  return rand + "px";
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed compared to the original code.

Comment: He moved the `getElementById` inside the Starz function.

Comment: Turns out I had to move the script to the bottom of the body. I always mess that up. Thank you all for the help though!